# Rewriting a Url which can contain 1 or 2 querystrings with URLRewriter.NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-config, url-rewriting, urlrewriter.net

In my project, my /PropertDetail.aspx can get 2 querystrings.

**1st** one for the PropertyId `/PropertDetail.aspx?PropertyId=5`

**2nd** one for the Language `/PropertDetail.aspx?PropertyId=5&Language=2`

**EDIT:** and this page can get one of them or can get both of them, so my rewriter rule needs to handle both of them

So, i have set these rules to web.config

```
<rewriter>
        <rewrite url="^(/.+(\.gif|\.png|\.jpg|\.ico|\.pdf|\.css|\.js)(\?.+)?)$" to="$1" processing="stop" />
        <rewrite url="^/(.+)-(.+).aspx$" to="/PropertyDetail.aspx?PropertyId=$2" processing="stop"/>
        <!--http://localhost:1562/Harika-Gayrimenkul-5.aspx-->
        <rewrite url="^/(.+)-(.+)-(.+).aspx$" to="/PropertyDetail.aspx?PropertyId=$2&#038;Language=$3" processing="stop"/>
        <!--http://localhost:1562/Great-Property-5-2.aspx-->
</rewriter>
```

It is all OK if there is no Language querystring, but when there is a language querystring it gets the 3rd expression as the *PropertyId* instead of *Language*

How can i define these two rules for the same page ?

Thanks

Comment: I've got a lot closer, take a look. Beware of what else this may unintentionally match though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combined answer:

```
<rewriter>
    <rewrite url="^(/.+(\.gif|\.png|\.jpg|\.ico|\.pdf|\.css|\.js)(\?.+)?)$" to="$1" processing="stop"/>
    <rewrite url="^.+?([\d]+?)-([\d]+?)\.aspx$" to="/PropertyDetail.aspx?PropertyId=$1&amp;Language=$2" processing="stop"/>
    <rewrite url="^.+?-([\d]+?)\.aspx$" to="/PropertyDetail.aspx?PropertyId=$1" processing="stop"/>

</rewriter>
```

That's working well now for many combinations:

```
/This-is-a-really-long-property-title-555-12
```

returns PropertyId=555 and Language=12.

```
/This-is-another-really-long-property-title-666
```

returns PropertyId=666.

Comment: it didnt work out. But there is something that i forgot to mention about, the length of the string may be much more like Great-Property-For-People

When i use the rules above my querystring gets PropertyId="Great-Estate-5-2"

Comment: Just testing it. Found out it's not working quite right.

So the number of dashes before the required ids is variable?

Comment: Great-Estate-5-2
Property Title=Great Estate | PropertyId=5 | LanguageId=2

Comment: There you go try the new one working for me.
And for more than one digit now as well, as I assume your IDs will get to more than 10 :)

Comment: :) thank you very much, i have tried it and it s ok when i have 2 querystrings(propertyId and the Language) but if i have just only PropertyId querystring i get an error. Saying Source can not be found 404. What might be the reason :/

Comment: now my problem is with that url

/Great-Property-10

if there is just one querystring there is a problem, but if there is two querystring it works great

Comment: @Barbaros, take what teknohippy has and add a third rewrite rule to the end:  <rewrite url="^.+?-([\d]+?)\.aspx$" to="/PropertyDetail.aspx?PropertyId=$1" processing="stop"/>

Comment: @Barbaros, for future reference in this case the 404 means that nothing was matched by any rule.

Comment: Thank you very much teknohippy for your help and JasonMArcher for the last golden shot :) adding <rewrite url="^.+?-([\d]+?)\.aspx$" to="/PropertyDetail.aspx?PropertyId=$1" processing="stop"/> as the third rule did the trick

Comment: @teknohippy, could you please add this as the 3rd rule, i will mark it as answer. <rewrite url="^.+?-([\d]+?)\.aspx$" to="/PropertyDetail.aspx?PropertyId=$1" processing="stop"/>

Answer (score 2):

Make the second parameter (the language value) optional in the match by adding a question mark:

*Edit: this is a corrected version, made after I realized that I misunderstood the question a bit.*

```
<rewriter>
  <rewrite url="\.(?:gif|png|jpg|ico|pdf|css|js)(?:\?.*)?$" to="$0" processing="stop"/>
  <rewrite url="(\d+)(?:-?(\d+)?)\.aspx$" to="/PropertyDetail.aspx?PropertyId=$1&amp;Language=$2" processing="stop"/>
</rewriter>
```

This is a cleaned-up and streamlined version of what the OP has working. It will produce output in the form of

```
/PropertyDetail.aspx?PropertyId=12345&Language=1   (when language is present)
/PropertyDetail.aspx?PropertyId=12345&Language=    (when it isn't)
```

Note

- the use of the $0 back-reference to refer to the entire input string, without the need to actually *match* the entire input string
- the use of non-capturing groups (?:...) for things we don't need to store in a match-group because we don't want to retrieve their value later
- the collapse of the separate rules for single and double-argument URLs into a single rule

---

Original version of the answer:

```
<rewriter>
  <rewrite url="^/(.+?)-(.+?)-?(.+?)?\.aspx$" to="/PropertyDetail.aspx?PropertyId=$2&amp;#038;Language=$3" processing="stop"/>
</rewriter>
```

Comment: That's what i am looking for but i got an error saying System.ArgumentException: "^/(.+?)-(.+?)-?(.+?+)?\.aspx$

Comment: Still the varying number of dashes is going to cause trouble.

Comment: Regarding the argument exception: Maybe the backslash needs to be escaped (double backslashes instead of one)?

Comment: Now the exception s gone but can't get querystrings now. thank you for your time and effort. What might be the proplem, have u ever used urlrewriter.net component

Answer (score 1):

This is the final solution that we have come up with.

```
<rewriter>
    <rewrite url="^(/.+(\.gif|\.png|\.jpg|\.ico|\.pdf|\.css|\.js)(\?.+)?)$" to="$1" processing="stop"/>
    <rewrite url="^.+?([\d]+?)-([\d]+?)\.aspx$" to="/PropertyDetail.aspx?PropertyId=$1&amp;Language=$2" processing="stop"/>
    <rewrite url="^.+?-([\d]+?)\.aspx$" to="/PropertyDetail.aspx?PropertyId=$1" processing="stop"/>
</rewriter>
```

- 1st rule is about the file types
  which we don't need.
- 2nd rule is about "if page gets 2
  querystring"
- 3rd rule is about if the page get
  only one querystring

Thank you very much for your helps **teknohippy** and **JasonMArcher**

Comment: @Barbaros Alp: I think I misread your original question a bit, I somhow thought you had *three* parameters. You could collapse your 2nd and 3rd rule into one: <rewrite url="^.+?(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?\.aspx$" to="/PropertyDetail.aspx?PropertyId=$1&amp;Language=$2" processing="stop"/>

Comment: At least if you don't mind that the "Language" parameter would always be *there* in the end, though sometimes empty.

Comment: Oh, and I've updated my answer accordingly. Not that it would make much of a difference at this point, but I did not want to leave it incorrect. ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much Tomalak, i have checked your answer, really thank you very much for your help.